# How do I input multiple values from a single line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to take a line input in python
Consider I need to take input in a line consisting integers seperated by spaces
I want to give 5 6 and store them in a and b

```
a=input()
b=input()
```

If I take in above format, it takes only when I press enter

Comment: what python version?

Comment: The [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input) function "… reads a line from input …", which is why you have to hit enter after for each value. To accept multiple values on a line, you want to just `input` once, then parse the line (which is easy, as @saliesh shows).

Comment: I've tagged this with python-3.x, because the accepted answer is wrong for 2.x. If you're on 2.x, please edit to change the tag, and leave @saliesh a comment so he can change his answer appropriately (to use `raw_input`, and to explain why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple

```
j,k=input().split(" ")
j=int(j)
k=int(k)
```

Comment: `input().split()` does the same thing you don't need `" "`

Comment: As a one-line solution `j,k = map(int, input().split())`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: In fact, it's probably better to use `split()`; if the user types `3  4` with two spaces, it will probably be surprising to get a `ValueError: too many tuple values to unpack (expected 2)`…

Comment: @PadraicCunningham and sailesh thank you for all your reply's , Padric method seems to be good